# C++ program in xcode return just Build Succeeded

Tags: c++, xcode

I'm trying use pylon library for work with industrial camera (Basler ACE acA1600-20uc). 
I started with examples program for grabbing pictures from camera.
Problem is, that example program is "Build Succeeded" (xcode) but nothing happens. Command line is still clean, no logs, no exit code. Nothing. I expect some informations because several cout << in code below.
Where's the problem? Give me some hint. Thank you.

```
    // Grab.cpp
/*
    Note: Before getting started, Basler recommends reading the Programmer's Guide topic
    in the pylon C++ API documentation that gets installed with pylon.
    If you are upgrading to a higher major version of pylon, Basler also
    strongly recommends reading the Migration topic in the pylon C++ API documentation.

    This sample illustrates how to grab and process images using the CInstantCamera class.
    The images are grabbed and processed asynchronously, i.e.,
    while the application is processing a buffer, the acquisition of the next buffer is done
    in parallel.

    The CInstantCamera class uses a pool of buffers to retrieve image data
    from the camera device. Once a buffer is filled and ready,
    the buffer can be retrieved from the camera object for processing. The buffer
    and additional image data are collected in a grab result. The grab result is
    held by a smart pointer after retrieval. The buffer is automatically reused
    when explicitly released or when the smart pointer object is destroyed.
*/

// Include files to use the PYLON API.
#include <pylon/PylonIncludes.h>
#ifdef PYLON_WIN_BUILD
#    include <pylon/PylonGUI.h>
#endif

// Namespace for using pylon objects.
using namespace Pylon;

// Namespace for using cout.
using namespace std;

// Number of images to be grabbed.
static const uint32_t c_countOfImagesToGrab = 100;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    // The exit code of the sample application.
    int exitCode = 0;

    // Before using any pylon methods, the pylon runtime must be initialized. 
    PylonInitialize();

    try
    {
        // Create an instant camera object with the camera device found first.
        CInstantCamera camera( CTlFactory::GetInstance().CreateFirstDevice());

        // Print the model name of the camera.
        cout << "Using device " << camera.GetDeviceInfo().GetModelName() << endl;

        // The parameter MaxNumBuffer can be used to control the count of buffers
        // allocated for grabbing. The default value of this parameter is 10.
        camera.MaxNumBuffer = 5;

        // Start the grabbing of c_countOfImagesToGrab images.
        // The camera device is parameterized with a default configuration which
        // sets up free-running continuous acquisition.
        camera.StartGrabbing( c_countOfImagesToGrab);

        // This smart pointer will receive the grab result data.
        CGrabResultPtr ptrGrabResult;

        // Camera.StopGrabbing() is called automatically by the RetrieveResult() method
        // when c_countOfImagesToGrab images have been retrieved.
        while ( camera.IsGrabbing())
        {
            // Wait for an image and then retrieve it. A timeout of 5000 ms is used.
            camera.RetrieveResult( 5000, ptrGrabResult, TimeoutHandling_ThrowException);

            // Image grabbed successfully?
            if (ptrGrabResult->GrabSucceeded())
            {
                // Access the image data.
                cout << "SizeX: " << ptrGrabResult->GetWidth() << endl;
                cout << "SizeY: " << ptrGrabResult->GetHeight() << endl;
                const uint8_t *pImageBuffer = (uint8_t *) ptrGrabResult->GetBuffer();
                cout << "Gray value of first pixel: " << (uint32_t) pImageBuffer[0] << endl << endl;

#ifdef PYLON_WIN_BUILD
                // Display the grabbed image.
                Pylon::DisplayImage(1, ptrGrabResult);
#endif
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "Error: " << ptrGrabResult->GetErrorCode() << " " << ptrGrabResult->GetErrorDescription() << endl;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (const GenericException &e)
    {
        // Error handling.
        cerr << "An exception occurred." << endl
        << e.GetDescription() << endl;
        exitCode = 1;
    }

    // Comment the following two lines to disable waiting on exit.
    cerr << endl << "Press Enter to exit." << endl;
    while( cin.get() != '\n');

    // Releases all pylon resources. 
    PylonTerminate();  

    return exitCode;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check if you are compiling the app target, not a framework or other  .. take a look at the right of RUN/STOp button

Answer (score 0):

Oh yes, 
you are right thank you! Because it is a lot of examples in one project i've builded something other again and again. :)